# how to scan multiple directory using java multi threading

Tags: java, multithreading

The problem statement is, you have to list the name of the files from the given directory, you have given one directory structure which has some subdirectory and some file in them.

I did some part of the code but it is not working can you please help me what is the correct way of doing it.

**code**

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    RunableExample run = new RunableExample();
    Thread th = new Thread(run, "thread1");
    String directoryName = "C:\\Users\\GUR35893\\Desktop\\CleanupMTM";
    File directory = new File(directoryName);
    File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
    RunableExample.MyList = new ArrayList<File>();
    for (File file : fList) {
        RunableExample.MyList.add(file);
    }
    try {
        th.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
  }
 }

 public class RunableExample implements Runnable {
public static List<File> MyList;
int count = 0;
File filepath;

public void run() {
    try {
        while (count < MyList.size()) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ">>>>"
                    + MyList.size() + " >>>>> " + count);
            filepath = MyList.get(count);

            if (filepath != null && filepath.isFile()) {

                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " >>"
                        + filepath.getAbsolutePath());
            } else {
                synchronized (this) {
                    if (filepath != null) {
                        // System.out.println("Else");
                        RunableExample run3 = new RunableExample();
                        Thread th3 = new Thread(run3, "thread" + count);
                        File[] fList = filepath.listFiles();
                        // System.out.println("Else1");
                        for (File file : fList) {
                            MyList.add(file);
                        }
                        th3.start();
                    }
                }
            }
            count++;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e);

    }

}
}
```

Comment: This problem is most likely I/O bound (unless you search across several physical disks) so using multiple threads is not going to be a big win.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a directory (including sub-directories) and you want list all files.
The simplest yet effective approach would be iterate through a directory, there will be just 2 options either its a file or its a directory.

If it's a file, simply name it, don't spawn a new thread for it.
If it's a directory, spawn a new thread and re-use the same code for traversing the files or sub-directories in that directory in the newly spawned thread.

If you could give a sample output then maybe we can help further. But till then, I don't see any use of synchronization in the code.

Comment: this is a single thread solution. the processing time will increase when the number of Sub-directory gets increase.

Comment: Read para 2 carefully of my answer. Each subdirectory means a new thread, which I would ideally control by a FixedThreadPoolExecutor

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of @Himanshu Answer.

```
import java.io.File;

class Lister extends Thread{
    String basepath;

    Lister(String basepath){
        this.basepath = basepath;
    }
     @Override
     public void run(){
         File rootDir = new File(basepath);

         for(File f : rootDir.listFiles()){
             if(f.isDirectory())
                 new Lister(f.toString()).start();
             else
                 System.out.println(f);
         }
     }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Lister("/").start();
    }
}
```

This code works, but make sure it don't memory overflow for huge directory trees. For that you can add extra checks to spawn only directory you need.

Comment: Hi Himanshu, you are correct but my requirement is whenever new directory found spawn the new thread for it to enhance the process time. the suggestion you have given is working only one thread. if there are thousands of subdirectory and files are available then the response time will be an increase. therefore the objective is spawning the thread for each directory.

Comment: New thread will be spawned for each directory, kindly examine the code again!